# Are there full price graphs of currently traded stocks?

Tags: historical-data, current-events

If so, where are they? Robinhood limits graphs to 5 years and TD Ameritrade limits them to 3. I am interested in finding full data of stock prices from the start to now. I am investing in the Dow index.

It's like they don't want their users making informed decisions based on the history of currently traded stocks and is giving me a bad image of stock brokerages.

Comment: Questions seeking product/service recommendations are specifically off-topic here. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google "Free Charts Stocks Historical" and you'll find a number of web sites that provide charts of stocks with varying amounts of historical data.  They'll usually provide up to 1/2 a dozen time periods of less than a year, YTD and up to 1/2 a dozen time periods in years.  I've seen as much as 50 years of data but obviously, the resolution for such a long period of time is poor.

Some notable names out there include MarketWatch, Yahoo Finance, StockCharts, Macrotrends. TradingView, et al.

I'll spare you all of the reasons why but given that most major discount brokers now charge no commissions, it makes no sense at all to trade at Robinhood.  It's a second rate broker.

Comment: What broker do you recommend? I understand Robinhood is bad for day trading and buying fractional shares. Why else is it second rate?

Comment: Market watch was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! MacroTrends was a close second.

Comment: You're welcome.  Why else is it second rate?  If you don't mind, post it as a new question.  Space is limited in comments.

Answer (score 0):

https://finance.yahoo.com has more data that 5 years, but it does not have entire history. For GE for example, it has data since 1968, but company is around for bit more: it's actually only continuously operating constituent of the original DJIA from 1896.

Regarding conspiracy to keep investors uninformed - I don't think there is such conspiracy: digitizing old data costs money, and it's probably of a limited use for an investor. Also, you can get more data by subscribing to Reuters or Bloomberg terminal.